# ¿Porque no Accedo a mi web desde una red externa? Solo de forma local

Tags: webservice, servidor, redes, virtualhost

Seré breve, tengo un servidor local en el cual tengo un par de web alojadas y configuradas con virtualhost a una misma ip publica(es fija),los host los tengo alojados en no-ip apuntados a mi ip publica pero tengo las siguientes situaciones:

-Al acceder al sitio con el host de no-ip desde mi red local **puedo acceder**, ya sea desde cualquier pc o celular(mientras este en mi red),**ojo uso el nombre del host NO mi ip local**.

-Al acceder desde una red externa (Ej.Ciber o Datos moviles) **no me muestra la web**.

-**No puedo hacer ping a mi ip publica**,lo cual no entiendo ya que en el primer caso puedo acceder **con el host** que apunta a mi ip publica.

Saben cual sea la razon de ya que no entiendo cual es la falla,Uso el puerto 80. Gracias

Comment: Que puerto estas usando? 80 u otro?

Comment: estoy usando el puerto 80

Comment: Cuando dices que no te muestra la web, te refieres a que te presenta una página sin contenido o a que devuelve un error http?

Comment: Tu router tiene algún firewall?, si de manera interna acepta y de afuera no, es muy probable que este bloqueando conexiones remotas.

Comment: 1. Que el ping no responda, puede ser que el router no responda. Es una configuración de seguridad muy comun
2. El problema seguramente es que necesitas crear un port forwarding en el router. Tu router usa NAT, es decir, tus direcciones IP internas son distintas que tu ip publica. Aunque tengas solo 1 computadora en tu red interna, debes decirle al router que las solicitudes al puerto 80 deben redireccionarse a tu ip interna. Revisa la configuración de tu router, o busca "port forwarding" para tu router en internet.

Comment: Cuando acceso desde fuera manda la típica imagen del buscador que no puede acceder a la pagina,@GabrielJeremyRodriguezRiver Si tiene pero, en ese caso creo que tampoco me dejaría acceder desde dentro con el host y solo con la ip del servidor, cosa que no es así ya que desde dentro puedo acceder con el host(lo que quiere decir que entra por la ip publica)

Comment: @AlexAngelico ya he creado la regla que indica que todo paquete entrante a mi ip publica por puerto 80 sea redireccionado al servidor(su ip) y de igual manera en el servidor he creado la regla de firewall para que acepte entradas por puerto 80. Todas esas configuraciones ya las están activas sin éxito.

Comment: ¿Qué servidor estás usando? ¿Usas algún programa para manejarlo/configurarlo (p.e. WampServer, XAMPP o similares)?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Tengo Windows server 2016 y uso WampServer

Comment: @Riu ¿en WampServer le has dado a hacer el servidor público?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Asi es, ya que como comento desde cualquier dispositivo que esta en mi red puedo acceder, porque se redirecciona por el firewall de la red,pero desde Internet ya no es posible entrar.